# Is AgensGraph heavy compared to the other graph database?

Tags: postgresql, graph-databases, agens-graph

I have a question while I'm using AgensGraph.
I know the AgensGraph is developed based on PostgreSQL.
So I thought it might be heavy because PostgreSQL is included into AgensGraph.
But I didn't feel like it's heavy when I use it. Just that is what I'm curious.

Comment: What do you mean with "heavy"?

Comment: I mean, for example, general application needed the installation is light to use it. But PostgreSQL is in the AgensGraph. So I'm curious how handle the memory, storage and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand your concern is whether AgensGraph consumes many resources or not. It depends on how you configure the database server. In AgensGraph there are many configuration parameters most of which are inherited from PostgreSQL. In default, the configuration is minimized not to consume many resources, which is not appropriate for in-production.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I got that now :)